# Is it possible to export groups to seperate PSD file?

Tags: javascript, export, photoshop, photoshop-script

Is there any script can export groups in a psd file to a seperate psd file with group's name and layers in it?

[image: Original psd]
[image: psd 1]
[image: psd 2]

I have a lot of psd file that need to export the groups like this.
I also found some script but it just save as PNG or JPG.

Comment: Working with groups is a pain. Have you had a look at [this](https://community.adobe.com/t5/photoshop-ecosystem-discussions/export-groups-to-files/td-p/2140329) You may have to update the script for the current version.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to export groups to separate PSD files in Photoshop. Follow these steps:

1. Right-click (or Control-click on Mac) on the group folder.
2. From the context menu that appears, select "Duplicate Group" or "Duplicate Group to Document"[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mp4Wo.png)
3. A dialog box will open. Choose "New" to create a new document for the duplicated group.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FsMmP.png)
4. Click "OK" to create the new document with the duplicated group.

Comment: Many thanks Ani,
But I'm using Windows and I have thounsand files like this, it's impossible to manual work.
Anw, thank you for your comment.